# How to pass json data in swift app between two viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, swift2

I need help with passing json data.I have json data in this array

```
var TableData:Array< String > = Array < String >()
```

In this Array I have Name,Address,Latitude, Longitude

I show Name and Address in a tableView , but I would like to create annotation in different viewController with Latitude and Longitude depending on which cell user taps(Name,Adress,latitude,Longitude shoulld be equal) , so I am asking you if there is some good tutorial in swift , or if you have just some advice. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
let newController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("newControllerIdentifier") as! NewControllerClassName
newController.data = array
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newController, animated: true)
```

It also appears you are using a array of string type that are comma separated.
I would rather create a variable like below

```
var jsonArray:[[String:String]]?
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to pass data from one swift file to another. In the case that there is a rootViewController and a button is clicked to open a new ViewController. Having previously defined an array in the new ViewController, the json parsed array can be passed along using the prepareForSegue method.
Another popular way to pass information between different swift files would be using the `AppDelegate`. Here you can create instances of different swift classes using a method known as `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("identifier")`. This can be done by creating a storyboard variable then calling this method by doing `storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("identifier")`.

```
let newvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("newvcIdentifier") as! (UIViewController extended class)
newvc.data = TableData
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newController, animated: true)
```

where newvc has a variable declared as follows:

```
var data: Array <String>!
```

Another method that can be used is having shared data among all of the classes using a singleton. A singleton can be created very simply in swift3, take a look [here](https://krakendev.io/blog/the-right-way-to-write-a-singleton) for details.

```
class JSONData {
    var json: Array <String>
    static let sharedInstance = JSONData()
}
```

Before segueing to the next vc, you should store the data in the sharedInstance class. This should be done by overriding the prepare method. Documentation on this method can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare)

```
sharedInstance.json = self.json
```

Once the data is set in the shared instance, after the new view controller is loaded, this data can be accessed through `sharedInstance.json`.

Hope this works for you and just comment if you have any other questions!

Answer (score 0):

> so I am asking you if there is some good tutorial in swift

http://matteomanferdini.com/how-ios-view-controllers-communicate-with-each-other/

He covers clean code and best practices. Better read this before implementing anything.

> or if you have just some advice

Your code needs to be clean. Passing latitude as String it's going to create you a problem later (conversions, code understanding, or even bugs).
Make a new account here and watch uncle Bob. His lessons are valuable. matteomanferdini above follow uncle bob practices. 
https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/clean-code/9780134661742/